# Docker mysql instant exit

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with Mysql Docker which exits when I run my `docker-compose up` command.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: "2"
services:
    web:
        build: ./app
        links:
            - "db-mongo:db-mongo"
            - "db-mysql:db-mysql"
        ports:
            - "443:3000"
        volumes:
            - "./app:/src"
            - "/src/.sass-cache"
            - "/src/node_modules"
            - "/src/lib"

    db-mongo:
        build: ./mongo
        ports:
            - "27017:27017"
        volumes:
            - "./mongo/db:/data"

    db-mysql:
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - "./mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "./mysql/log:/var/log/mysql"
            - "./mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: testt
```

Folders `./mysql/db` and `./mysql/log` are empty.

When I run `docker-compose up`, here the output :

```
db-mysql_1  | Initializing database
server_db-mysql_1 exited with code 1
```

When I run `docker ps -a` :
    0a5a7a643f18        mysql                   "docker-entrypoint.sh"   8 minutes ago       Exited (1) 7 minutes ago     server_db-mysql_1

The strange thing is if I run `docker run -d --name=new-mysql -p 3306:3306 -v /var/www/server/mysql/db:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mysql` it works...

And here the output of `docker logs 97c -f`:

```
Initializing database
Database initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/Factory' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.


MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
```

Why does my docker-compose can't keep alive my mysql docker ? I must missing something... Help ! Thanks

EDIT : It appears it is my `conf.d` folder which is making some problems, because when I remove volume `- "./mysql/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d"`, server_db-mysql keeps alive.

Here is the `mysql/conf.d/my.cnf` file content :

```
[mysqld]
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log = 1
```

Why does that file is crashing the mysql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a permission issue when mounting `/var/log/mysql` in your custom config file.

Please reference this issue [#docker-mysql-146](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/146) for the solution:

The owner and group of the `/var/log/mysql` directory has to be as expected by mysql. Ensure that, execute:

```
docker exec mysql chown mysql:root /var/log/mysql
```